# Testing gitlab-runner run command in a separate shell?

Tags: bash, background-process, gitlab-ci-runner, bats-core

### Context

While testing the functions of an installation script that automatically installs and runs GitLab and GitLab runners, I experienced some difficulties running the GitLab runner in the background an proceeding with the tests. (My intention is to simply run the runner in the background, and then to run a few tests that verify the service behaves as expected). However, when my test executes the function that executes the `sudo gitlab-runner run` command, the test hangs, waiting on the service to stop, (but the service should not stop).

### Function

```
# Run GitLab runner service
run_gitlab_runner_service() {
    run_command=$(sudo gitlab-runner run &)
    echo "service is running"
}
```

The output of the test is:

```
 Configuration loaded                                builds=0                                                                                     7/7
```

And then the cursor just keeps blinking while the last runner is successfully awaiting instructions.

### Test Code

```
@test "Test if the GitLab Runner CI service is running correctly." {
    run_service_output=$(run_gitlab_runner_service)
    EXPECTED_OUTPUT="service is running"
        
    assert_equal "$run_service_output" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}
```

However, when inspecting the regular output of the `sudo gitlab-runner run` command, I observe that it starts a new line/shell/something without asking. For example:

```
(base) name@name:~$ sudo gitlab-runner run &
[1] 84799
(base) name@name:~$ Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=84800 revision=8925d9a0 version=14.1.0
Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
Running in system-mode.                            
                                                   
Configuration loaded                                builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
```

basically, the output `(base) name@name:~$ Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64`  should never stop (until manually terminated), so I think the test is waiting on that shell/output to complete.

### Note

For completeness, I do not type the `(base) name@name:~$ Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 ..` output, that somehow is pushed to the terminal in the new line some how. I do not know exactly why this isn't just under the previous/original `(base) name@name:~$` that ran the `sudo gitlab-runner run &` command.

### Question

How can I ensure the function and test proceed after starting the `gitlab-runner run` service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was found by redirecting the output of the command to `/dev/null`.

### Code

```
# Run GitLab runner service
run_gitlab_runner_service() {
    output=$(nohup sudo gitlab-runner run &>/dev/null &)
    echo "service is running"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a slightly different syntax in order to run `gitlab-runner` in background

```
# Run GitLab runner service
run_gitlab_runner_service() {
    ( run_command="$(sudo gitlab-runner run)" ) &
    echo "service is running"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! The behaviour with your solution is identical to the described behaviour in the question. Basically, when run without a test environment, it starts the `Runtime platfom ..` and hangs in there until `enter` is pressed. When it is called from the test, no output is displayed and the caret/cursor keeps blinking indefinitely.

Comment: Maybe it's just an issue related to sudo? What is the behaviour if you remove `sudo` in `run_command` (`gitlab-runner` does not need to be run as root)?

Comment: Without `sudo` the behaviour is the same, except I also get `ERROR: Failed to load config stat /home/name/.gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory  builds=0` because the rest of the GitLab and GitLab runner installation is currently built such that it does require `sudo`. Hence, I think one can conclude it is not a sudo issue.